# How to solve a long "Wait" time, on a dedicated server of a pretty large website

Tags: linux, centos6, pause

Thanks for reading this.
We got an issue with our web server, we have a rather large website, with 500-800 concurrent users at any time, we use a dedicated server to host it, we use prefork to increase the speed of the Apache, but recently we experience a problem where our website takes longer then usual to load, tested it out in pingdom tools shows that the "wait" time it the main factor.

Also attached a screen shot of the "top" command.

Any help and tips will be highly appreciated.

Top command:
http://postimg.org/image/o2g777lwp/

Pingdom screenshot:
http://postimg.org/image/b9s37aaax/

httpd.conf relevant settings:

```
<IfModule worker.c>
ThreadLimit         64
ServerLimit         16
StartServers        4
MinSpareThreads     64
MaxSpareThreads     128
ThreadsPerChild     64
MaxClients          1024
MaxRequestsPerChild  0
</IfModule>
```

*We have a complex perl script running.

System spec: 16Gb ram , 4 core cpu

---

ThreadLimit         64
ServerLimit         16
StartServers        4
MinSpareThreads     64
MaxSpareThreads     128
ThreadsPerChild     64
MaxClients          1024
MaxRequestsPerChild  0

Comment: What content are you typically serving? Did you consider moving your static content to a CDN? What sort of server side language are you using? Did you take a look at the Apache status page?

Comment: Could be interresting to check for database long queries also

Comment: Bugger me, Load average of 158.  Your server is seriously overcommitted.

Comment: Can you post the worker config from apache2.conf, and /proc/cpuinfo for the record?

Comment: @TomO'Connor - I've supplied this info, would appreciate if you could let me know what you think.

What's the right way to calculate the settings of the worker in apache ?

Thanks in advnace!